# Linq-to-entities orderby gives ambiguous column name error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've created a query in Linq-to-entities (4.0), which has me confused, as I join on a few tables, two of which share a column name (DateCreated).  When I try to use orderby between the two tables with the same column name I get the following error: 'Column 'DateCreated' in order clause is ambiguous'

I'm confused as I thought specifying the table would mean it would pass that through to the SQL query.  In the example below I specify 'orderby a.Datecreated', but in the TSQL it only has ORDER BY `DateCreated`, when I would've expected to see ORDER BY `Extent1`.`DateCreated`.

```
using (PDFActionsEntities pdfEntities = new PDFActionsEntities())
{
    var actions = (from a in pdfEntities.PDFActions
               join f in pdfEntities.Files on a.FileID equals f.FileID into list1
               from l1 in list1.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join wp in pdfEntities.WebPages on a.WebPageID equals wp.webpageid into list2
               from l2 in list2.DefaultIfEmpty()
               orderby a.DateCreated
               select new
               {
                   ID = a.ID,
                   FileID = a.FileID,
                   WebPageID = a.WebPageID,
                   UserID = a.UserID,
                   FilePath = l1.Path,
                   URLPath = l2.url,
                   DateCreated = a.DateCreated
               });

}
```

Here is the T-SQL it creates

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`FileID`, 
`Extent1`.`ID`, 
`Extent1`.`WebPageID`, 
`Extent1`.`UserID`, 
`Extent2`.`Path`, 
`Extent3`.`url`, 
`Extent1`.`DateCreated`
FROM `tblpdfactions` AS `Extent1` LEFT OUTER JOIN
 `tblfiles` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`FileID` = `Extent2`.`FileID` LEFT OUTER JOIN 
`tblwebpageprints` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent1`.`WebPageID` = `Extent3`.`webpageid`
ORDER BY `DateCreated` ASC
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

P.S.  It's connecting to MySQL if that makes any difference.

---

EDIT:

Just after I asked the question, I saw another question based on a Left Join, which led to me to write:

```
var actions = (from a in pdfEntities.PDFActions
           join f in pdfEntities.Files on a.FileID equals f.FileID into list1
           from l1 in list1.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join wp in pdfEntities.WebPages on a.WebPageID equals wp.webpageid into list2
           from l2 in list2.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new 
           {
               ID = a.ID,
               FileID = a.FileID,
               WebPageID = a.WebPageID,
               UserID = a.UserID,
               FilePath = l1.Path,
               URLPath = l2.url,
               DateCreated = a.DateCreated
           }).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated);
```

I added the Orderby on the select new.  This now works.  However, I'm still confused as to why it wouldn't do the same thing when the orderby is in the main query.  Hey ho!  A bit annoying that I spent about 5 hours on this over a few days and within seconds of posting, I find the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to move `orderby` to the end of the query after the select keyword?
Like:

```
actions.OrderBy(a => a.DateCreated);
```

Comment: Yes, I've just tried that and it works.  I've amended the OP.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the TSQL is being generated as a partial construct of your specific select new statement. Have you tried altering the name of the property to something different like:

```
select new
{
    ID = a.ID,
    FileID = a.FileID,
    WebPageID = a.WebPageID,
    UserID = a.UserID,
    FilePath = l1.Path,
    URLPath = l2.url,
    Created = a.DateCreated  // Change is here
}
```

Comment: That last property was actually added in later, and did not affect the overall outcome.  @Pr0fess0rX gave pretty much the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveA: Yah, my answer was more of a swag. I up-voted him as soon as I saw his.